# What beamer environment is text within a frame?

Tags: beamer, color

I'm going crazy just trying to change the color of the text within a `frame` environment.

```
\begin{frame}[plain]
  I want this text to be red!!!
\end{frame}
```

I have tried almost every single environment listed on the [Latex Wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Presentations).

```
{
  %\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{dark_galaxy.jpg}}
  \begin{frame}[plain]
    \setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=red}
    \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{fg=red}
    \setbeamercolor{block body alerted}{fg=red}
    \setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=red}
    \setbeamercolor{block body example}{fg=red}
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=red,bg=blue}
    \setbeamercolor{fine separation line}{}
    \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=red}
    \setbeamercolor{item projected}{fg=red}
    \setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=red}
    \setbeamercolor{section in sidebar}{fg=red}
    \setbeamercolor{section in sidebar shaded}{fg=red}
    \setbeamercolor{separation line}{fg=red}
    \setbeamercolor{sidebar}{fg=red}
    \setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=red}
    \setbeamercolor{subsection in sidebar}{fg=red}
    \setbeamercolor{subsection in sidebar shaded}{fg=red}
    \setbeamercolor{title}{fg=red}
    \setbeamercolor{titlelike}{fg=red}

    Electromagnetic radiation from hydrogen gas in VIRGOHI 21 suggests it is
    part of a system with a mass of \approximately $10^{11}$ solar masses.
  \end{frame}
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For a single `frame` in a different colour, a regular `\color{<col>}` works:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \color{red}%
  I want this text to be red!!!
\end{frame}
\end{document}​
```

Comment: **Why on earth** isn't this listed in any of the tutorials!!!

Comment: @user545424: Because you should use the semantic commands provided by beamer, which *are* discussed. (Btw, have a look at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors.)

Comment: @Caramdir From my understanding, user545424 is *asking* for the Beamer semantics to set this style --- not the tex/latex command to locally override text color as provided in this answer. It seems like user545424 exhaustively explored the Beamer styling commands that were documented, and didn't find any setting that controlled text color. In fact, this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/238807/28304 on a question marked as duplicate to this one is the closest I can find to a real answer.

Answer (score 13):

To highlight some text in beamer, use `\alert{some text}`.

From the `beamer` tutorial (specifically Section 3.8)

> `beamer` offers the command `\alert`, which
>       is used like `\emph` and, by default, typesets its argument in bright red.

The command is again described in Section 12.3 of the manual, along with the `alertenv` environment.

Why doesn't changing the color of `normal text` work? The beamer manual says:

> The color [`normal text`] is used for normal text. At the beginning of the document the foreground color is installed as `\normalcolor`.

What this means is that it has to be changed before `\begin{document}` and then affects *all* frames. There doesn't seem to be an easy way around that particular limitation of the beamer's themes. I guess the reason for this (except for being easier to implement) is to force users to use semantic markup instead of constantly changing the `normal text` color.

Answer (score 4):

The question asks what Beamer styling commands to use to change the default color of text within a frame. Locally setting the text color [as suggested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61498/28304) works, but isn't quite what is being asked (as currently worded)—It doesn't use Beamer styling commands, as pointed out in the comments to that answer.

A more complete answer is provided with [this other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/238752/28304), which was closed as a duplicate to this one. User [oneself](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3768/oneself) [points out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/238807/28304) that
one should use `\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=red}` to set the text color globally, but this must be followed by `\usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text}` to take effect.

```
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=red}
\usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text}
\begin{frame}
  Some text in red
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Nice answer. I had set `\usebeamercolor{normal text}` and, for some reason, that applied the desired color only to some of the text. Adding the option `[fg]` did the trick for me.