# Change beamer normal text color per frame

Tags: beamer, themes

I would like to change the normal text color in a beamer frame with different colors for different frames.  In the following example, the frame title color changes correctly, but not the normal text color.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{Example}

\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=green}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=green}

\begin{document}

\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=red}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=red}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Red Title}
  Some text in red
\end{frame}

\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=blue}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Blue Title}
  Some text in blue
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: page 1]
[image: page 2]

Comment: Try `\usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text}` after `\setbeamercolor{...}` etc

Comment: That seems to work.  Why doesn't this get applied automatically?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Formalizing based on Christian's comment as an answer.

I added \usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text} as following:

```
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=red}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=red}
\usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Red Title}
  Some text in red
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Just a heads up, this answer is more complete than the accepted answer. Also, it looks like the duplicate (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61497/what-beamer-environment-is-text-within-a-frame) mark might be in error. That question was never *really* answered; This question/answer, however, actually tells you the Beamer styling syntax to configure slide text color. If anything, I wonder if that other question should be re-labelled as a duplicate of this one (if we're going to optimal quality)